# css header layout width 3 divs

Tags: css

I am trying to create a header with 3 divs: one is aligned left, one is aligned right and the other is in the center. [image]

the page is for example 1200px
the black,red and yellow rectangles are 960px and centered in the page.
elements in the black rectangle are added to the left,
elements in the yellwo rectangle are added to the right,
and the elements in the red tectangle are centered.

This is a good general case study for header of a site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your issue

```
<div class="header" style="width:1200px;">
<div style="width:40%;float:left;" class='black-one'>
    <div style='float:left;'>Some content</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:20%;float:left;" class='red-one'>
    <div style="margin:10px auto;text-align:center">Some content</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:40%;float:left;" class='yellow-one'>
<div style='float:right;text-align:right;'>Some content</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got the columns but the content must also be adjusted accordingly for each column.

Comment: This is a very nice overview, Thank you!

Comment: Thank You, but i suggest not to use inline css and instead use external css file for style. Could you please vote up if it help u?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on this a while back here is my code...

```
<div id="mainContent">

  <div id="col1">

    Column 1

  </div>

  <div id="col2">

    Column 2

  </div>

  <div id="col3">

    Column 3

  </div>

  <div id="clearance" style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

And here is the CSS for it....

```
#mainContent {

    width: 1000px;

    margin-right: auto;

    margin-left: auto;

    text-align: center;

}

#col1 {

    margin: 10px;

    float: left;

    width: 300px;

}

#col2 {

    margin: 10px;

    float: left;

    width: 300px;

}

#col3 {

    margin: 10px;

    float: left;

    width: 300px;

}
```

Hope this helps... Phillip Dews

Comment: You got the columns but the content must also be adjusted accordingly for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<style>
.header { margin: 0px auto; width: 1200px; }
.floatt { float: left; margin-right: 5px;}
.black-one { width: 40%;}
.red-one { width: 20%;}
.yellow-one { width: 40%;}
.clear { clear: both;}
</style>

<div class="header">
<div class='black-one floatt'>
Some content
</div>
<div class='red-one floatt'>
Some content
</div>
<div class='yellow-one floatt'>
Some content
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```